# Gradient of $A \mapsto \mbox{tr}(AB)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

While going through some notes on matrices, I stumbled upon the following

$$\nabla_A \mbox{tr}(AB) = B^T$$

where $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size. The trace operator returns a real number. How does the derivative of a scalar result in a matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be matrices such that their product $AB$ is a square matrix.

Another way to write the trace is to use the inner product (:) notation, i.e.
$${\rm tr}(AB) = A^T:B$$
Because of the cyclic property of the trace, this can also be written as $B^T:A$

So the differential of the function is simply
$$d\,{\rm tr}(AB) = A^T:dB + B^T:dA$$
Note that each term on the RHS is an inner product of two matrices, yielding a scalar result.

Depending on which variable you take to be the independent variable, the gradient is either
$$\nabla_B\,{\rm tr}(AB) = A^T$$
$$\nabla_A\,{\rm tr}(AB) = B^T$$