# Gradient of $X \mapsto \mbox{Tr}(AX)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I know that the gradient of $X \mapsto \mbox{Tr}(XA)$ is $A^T$.  However, how does this change if we had a scenario where $A$ and $X$ are swapped.  Is the gradient $X \mapsto \mbox{Tr}(AX)$ the same?

Also, how does this extend if we have more matrices? We can just assume everything before our "$X$" is $A$, correct? For example, $X \mapsto\mbox{Tr}\left(U^T V X\right)$. We can assume this is similar to the above where $U^TV$ is our "$A$" matrix, right?

Comment: Use the invariance of the trace map with respect to conjugation to show that $Tr(XA)=Tr(AX)$ and conclude.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Thanks. What about the scenario where you have something like tr( X^T A^T A X) then?  How would one work to derive that?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2573030/339790)

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**: ${\mathrm{d} f({X})= \text{trace}(M^T \mathrm{d} {X}) \iff \frac{\partial f}{\partial {X}} = M}$

---

In your case,

$$\mathrm d \ \text{trace}(AXB) = \text{trace}(\mathrm d  (AX B)) = \text{trace}(A \ \mathrm d X\  B) = \text{trace}(B A \ \mathrm d X)$$
and thus we identify $(BA)^T = A^T B^T$ as the derivative.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That makes sense.  I'm trying to work through some stuff I've read using the matrix cookbook but its rough keeping some stuff straight sometimes.

If you don't mind a follow-up then, so what if we have

trace(X^T  A^T  A  X) and we differentiate w.r.t. X here then?

My intuition is that we get (X^T A^T A)^T = (X A A^T), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Look at formula (108) in cookbook. maybe try to derive it like i did above

Comment: @Jibril You could also use Gateaux variation to calculate these matrix derivatives.

Comment: JackyChong Thanks', I'd have to look into that. Not familiar. @user365239 - What do you do when you can't find a form in the cookbook, by chance?  For example if we reversed the above and wanted it with respect to A, then (108) doesn't work.  trace( X^T A^T A X ) doesn't have an equivalent in the cookbook as far as I can make out.

Comment: Set $B = A^T A$

Comment: But I want to differentiate w.r.t A?

Comment: (116) . . . but you should try it by hand . . .

Comment: Thanks. I think I will do just that, since I'm not sure where that C factors in here.  My fear with doing it by hand is that, since I am so unfamiliar in this territory, that I will lead myself down the wrong path.  I appreciate your answers.

Comment: It's OK, set $C=I$ then it's the same as yours